# Communicating with Server - Android App

Tags: java, android, client-server, communication, android-doze-and-standby

I have an android application which is uploading and downloading a file in 
every 15 min. I am using **AlarmManager** **setRepeating()** to do this, but it is consuming lot of Battery and Inefficient. But i want to restructure this app so that it will work on Marshmallow and above devices.
I read about **JobScheduler** and **sync adapter** , but the challenge is **Doze mode** . As per Official Documentation

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_app_standby

JobScheduler and Sync Adapter wont work on Doze mode.

So, How to make android app and server communication for every 15 min, even in doze mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why this requirement of upload / download a file exactly every 15m? What is the need for that?

Comment: This is just an internal app, We are gathering some info from device and also providing some info from server.

Comment: If only internal, then imho way better to do it alike the system, so that you will do it at the 15th minute or at the first possible moment.

Answer (score 0):

As per  [Android developer documents](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) AlarmManager will continue work on marshmallow and above

Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.

1. If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use **setAndAllowWhileIdle()** or **setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()**.
2. Alarms **set** with **setAlarmClock()** continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Comment: Yes i read this one, but i want to switch it to Job scheduler. Because of wake lock app is consuming lot of battery.

Comment: Did you tried JobScheduler  on marshmallow devices? i don't think there is any problem of JobScheduler  with marshmallow. May be there is some issue in N devices but not in marshmallow.

Comment: Yes tried on N, and has some issue firing Jobs. My question is "Is it ok to continue with AlarmManager and manually whitelisting?" , Anyway this app is only for internal users not for All.

Comment: Yes there is no problem with alarmmanger you can go continue with it

Answer (score 0):

Use Alarmmanager and let your users deactivate Doze mode for your app (Whitelisting).

Alarmmanager do not consuming a lot of Battery. Alarm event comes from operating system.

Comment: Will Whitelisting the app work properly even in Doze mode for above Marshmallow ?

Comment: @PrakashBala Yes, in my app it works without problems